# Insert after trigger calling stored proc with insert statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

What will happen if an after insert trigger calls a stored procedure? This stored procedure has an `insert` statement into that table in question.

Will it go into a deadlock condition or is SQL Server smart enough to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to deal with the TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL, or the trigger will just keep (re)executing until you run out of resources.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187371.aspx

EDIT;;;;;;;;

Ooops.  Wrong link:

TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL (Transact-SQL)

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182737.aspx
```

Comment: Dhaval's link reminded me that it will run until it reaches the max nest level of 32.

Answer (score 2):

SQL server is smart enough to hadle this.
Please read following post

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/18/sql-server-2005-understanding-trigger-recursion-and-nesting-with-examples/